# HttpConnection.getContentLength() not available in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am trying to read the length of my responce by using "getContentLength()" of HttpConnection class..

but I am getting method getContentLength() not available error..

Is there any workaround to find length of the responce in blackberry..??

Below is my code snippet.

```
        HttpConnection httpconn = null;
        httpconn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(URL);
        httpconn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
        InputStream is = httpconn.openInputStream();
        fileSize = httpconn.getContentLength();
```

Thanks.

Comment: use httpConn.getLength()

Comment: @Ajmal: you should post that as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always get it from http headers:

```
long contentLength = Long.parseLong(httpconn.getHeaderField("Content-Length"));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can find length of the responce using  `httpConn.getLength()`